# How do I find the estimators for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from the method of moments?

Tags: distributions, inference

I have a random variable $X_1,\dots , X_n$ taken from a $\Gamma$ distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$. The population mean and variance are given by $E(X) = \alpha / \beta$ and $\text{Var}(x) = \alpha/\beta^{2}$. Could someone help? I'm struggling to find the method of moments to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (I just started learning inference)!

Comment: Set $\bar X = \alpha/\beta$ and $S^2 = \alpha/\beta^2,$ where $\bar X$ and $S^2$ are sample mean and variance, respectively. Then solve two nonlinear equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta.$ Those solutions will be MOM estimates $\check\alpha$ and $\check\beta,$ respectively. // Maybe try posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Comment continued: Here is R code to find method of moments estimates $\check\alpha=2.006,\check\beta = 5.021,$ for a sample of size $n=10^6$ from $\mathsf{Gamma}(\alpha=2,\beta=5).$ Not too bad.
However, somewhat messier [maximum likelihood estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Parameter_estimation) are
usually better, and more useful for smaller samples.

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rgamma(10^6, 2, 5)
a = mean(x);  v = var(x)
bta.est = a/v;  bta.est
[1] 5.021379
alp.est = a*bta.est;  alp.est
[1] 2.006028
```

If you post your analytic solution for method-of-moments estimators as an Answer, with a comment
to me, I will look at it.